# What is the approach to solve the following combinatorial problem?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I would like to request a hint on how to approach the problem below:

> The following are axioms for a (hitherto undefined) mathematical structure known as a bureaucracy. This consists of:
>
> - a set B of bureaucrats,
> - a set C of committees,
> - a relation S between B and C (read serves on), satisfying the following axioms:
>
>   - (B1) Every bureaucrat serves on at least three different committees.
>   - (B2) Every committee is served on by at least three different bureaucrats.
>   - (B3) Given two distinct committees, exactly one bureaucrat serves on both.
>   - (B4) Given two distinct bureaucrats, there is exactly one committe on which they both serve.
>
> 1. Prove from these axioms that if the number of bureaucrats is finite, so is the number of committees.
> 2. Prove that there are always at least seven bureaucrats in a bureaucracy, and find a bureaucracy with exactly seven bureaucrats.

Comment: Hint for the first part: Let $b$ denotes the number of bureaucrats. Using only (B2)and (B3) we get that the number of committees is at most the number of ways to choose $x$ bureaucrats with $3 \le x \le b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Each committee corresponds to a certain subset of bureaucrats. No two committees can have the exact same subset of bureaucrats (why?). Therefore, if there are $n$ bureaucrats, than there are at most $2^n$ committees.
2. - Consider a particular bureaucrat. They must be on at least three committees, and these committees must each have at least three members. Add up all of the bureaucrats mentioned so far.
   - This is tricky, I do not know how to give a hint without giving it away. Look up the Fano plane.